# Matrix rows and columns notation confusion

Tags: c++

There is this example in my text:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    double mat[3][3] ;  

    
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) // column index.
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) // row index.
        mat[i][j] = 10*(i+1) + (j+1) ;

    
    cout << "The matrix: " << endl ;
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) // column index.
    {
    cout << "[ " ;
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) // row index.
        cout << setw(4) << mat[i][j] ;
    cout << " ]" << endl ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Now what I found odd here is that the initial loop represents the column index while the 2nd one is the row index, which to me, is a bit unconventional. Usually we in mathematics use the first index for the row and the 2nd for the column.

My first question was, why does the compiler consider the first loop as the one moving along the columns while the 2nd moving in a row. It feels very arbitrary, no reason why this happens. Hence I did a test. I wrote the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    double mat[3][3];
    int k=0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
         for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
         {
            k++;
            mat[i][j]=k;
            
         }
    }
    
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        
        for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
           cout <<" " << mat[i][j];
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result here gives what I wanted and expected to give. The first loop represents the row index while the 2nd loop the column.

Now I am confused, why does the compiler now takes the reverse ? In the lecture example : first loop->column index, second loop -> row index. While in my example is the reverse. And in both cases the index of the first loop is in the first bracket, while the index of the 2nd loop in the 2nd bracket. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You've got this backwards.  In the first code post, `i` is the row index, not the column.  A 2d array is defined like `Type Name[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns]` and is access like `Name[row][col]`

Comment: `mat[i][j]=k;`  This is an out-of-bounds access when `i` or `j` is equal to 3.

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean the commentary is wrong? In the first example

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get a matrix with first element 1 and last one 9 . I do get this message though "stack smashing detected". But the matrix comes out

Comment: @imbAF --  *I get a matrix with first element 1 and last one 9* -- Doesn't matter.  It still is an out-of-bounds access, thus the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @imbAF Yes, your comments are wrong. In `for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) mat[i][j] = 10*(i+1) + (j+1) ;` `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index.

Comment: You should read this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) which explains this. According to it this stems from the way elements in a matrix are indexed in mathematics. And learning about row-major and column-major is certainly helpful if you want to optimize the performance of your code.

Comment: @NathanOliver that was the example I copy pasted here. So what was given in lecture was wrong, The commentary at least. But thanks for the clarification

Comment: @imbAF *I do get this message though "stack smashing detected"* -- The code is incorrect, regardless of what results you are getting.  When run with a different compiler or compiler options, you may not get anything except a crash.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. Thanks for the info. How would I need to change code, in order to correctly produce a 3x3 matrix (row -major) with numbers incrementing from 1 to 9?

Comment: @Mushroomator Thanks for the link. C++ is row major, and now I am certain as to how things wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @imbAF C++ arrays are 0-based, not 1-based.  `mat[i-1][j-1]=k;` is probably what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh right, the idex in a matrix or array starts from 0 to n-1. I totally forgot this. But with me starting from 1 to 3, what is the compiler doing ?

Comment: @imbAF it was already told to you, compiler is generating executable whose behavior is undefined. It is unlikely that you haven't seen any pieces of unstable software that somewhat seems to work until it doesn't.